# get code coverage percentage in cruisecontrol.net c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, code-coverage, cruisecontrol.net

I am trying to get code coverage in cruisecontrol.net. Using the following NANT script:

```
<target name="code_coverage" description="finds the code covered with tests">
  <exec program="${vstest_console}">
    <arg value="/Settings:CodeCoverage.runsettings" />
    <arg value="/EnableCodeCoverage" />
    <arg value="Tests.dll"/>
  </exec>
</target>
```

I am able to get a .coverage file. First of all the name of the .coverage file is coming as user name appended with current date time and under a folder named randomly. In .runsettings file documentation, i was unable to find anything about changing the name of .coverage file. I need to change name of this file. The bigger problem is that a sub-folder with some GUID type name is created into which the coverage file is dumped and it changes every time a test is run with code coverage ON.

Secondly can somebody help me in extracting covered path percentage out of this. I just need to fail the build, if coverage is below a point. Lot of help is available on Google but is of VS 2010 and before. I need help for VS 2012 or VS 2013. Currently am working on VS 2013 Ultimate and am using .runsettings file for code coverage.

Answer (score -1):

I still use the old mstest, but in the testsettings files,
there was / is an option to control a bit of the output folder :

```
  <NamingScheme baseName="cover_me" appendTimeStamp="false" useDefault="false" />
```

This is an child element of the TestSettings root element,
so the start of the file looks like this :

```
<TestSettings name="CodeCoverage" id="f5644e34-f879-42fe-8b36-d1ca1cc7c3c5" xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010">
  <Description>These are default test settings for a local test run.</Description>
  <NamingScheme baseName="cover_me" appendTimeStamp="false" useDefault="false" />
```

as for the percentages
with mstest I needed to convert the binary output to xml
I described the proces here : 
http://rubenwillems.blogspot.be/2011/09/setting-up-ccnet-in-combination-with.html
scroll a bit down for the coverage part. The source of the converter program is also there as the original page does not exist anymore :-(

From that point, it's only running an xslt to check if it's below a certain percentage.
This can be in the converter program, or as an extra task.

Comment: The problem with this code is that i have to define a path to go to .coverage file. But as stated I don't have a definite path. A sub-folder with some GUID type name is created into which the .coverage file is dumped. As of VS 2013 you can't use .testsettings for code coverage as evident from this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256991.aspx. Thats why i stated that I am working with .runsettings and VS 2013. I found this URL on google and this was helpful a lot. But -1 for this answer as this doen't work for latest VS.